# Parsing within a Set method

Tags: c#, string, parsing, int, tryparse

I know this might be a simple question but I was wondering in C# what is the best way to parse an incoming string within a set method to an int e.g. if I have 
`public int foo {get; set;}`

On the set I want to parse a incoming string

Comment: If your property type is int, you must set it with an int. If you need to convert from a string, then either make the property a string type or have the caller do the conversion (or add a helper method on the class).

Comment: How is parsing a single string to int related to a set at all? Why don't you use `foo = int.Parse(str);`? **Edit** Misunderstood the term "set", you mean the setter of a property. The best way is to parse it to int where you assign it to the property not in the property itself. Why should a property take care of your invalid input?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to skin this cat. This is how I would do it.

Let's say your property is:

```
public int Foo
{
   get { return _foo; }
   set { _foo = value; }
}
```

You could do is add a helper method on your class:

```
public void SetFoo(string sFoo)
{
   Foo = Convert.ToInt32(sFoo);
}
```

Then, when you need to set the value using a string, you can call that method:

```
myFooObject.SetFoo("4");
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have some `string` and you want to parse it into `int` by setter. Of course, you can do it, but the property must be `string`.

```
private int foo

public string Foo
{
    get 
    { 
        return foo.ToString();
    }

    set
    {
        foo = Int32.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

But remember that `Int32.Parse()` throws an exception if your string is not a number. You should consider using [`Int32.TryParse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) which could be a better choice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
private int _foo;
public int Foo 
{
  get { return _foo; }
  set 
  { 
    _foo = value; 
    ParseFoo(_foo);
  }
}
```

but since you're talking about strings...

```
private string _foo;
public string Foo 
{
    get { return _foo; }
    set {
        _foo = value;
        ParseIncomingString(_foo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since the property is of type `int`, it's not possible to assign a `string` to it. So you need to do this parsing before assigning the value to your property.

Alternatively you could make your setter *private*, and have a `public` method that takes `string`, and do your validation inside of the method set the property if validation succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to make sure that your value is an int before you set it to your property when the set method is called automatically. This means that the string you want to set to your property should be parsed before it's set.

If you want to do it as you asked then you could simply use the Int32.Parse(value) or Int32.TryParse(value).

The difference between those two is that Parse(value) method throws an exception if the the parsing fails which means that you have to use try-catch block if you want to catch the exception and where TryParse(value) returns false if the parsing fails and true on success.

You can read more at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397679.aspx